# Django Error NoReverseMatch at /invest/(?P1\d+)/

Tags: python, django, ajax

- So I am trying to update a value in django. But when clicking on submit it is throwing me a error.

```
NoReverseMatch at /invest/(?P1\d+)/
Reverse for 'invest' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['invest/\\(\\?P(?P<pk>[^/]+)\\\\d\\+\\)/$']
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/invest/(%3FP1%5Cd+)/
Django Version: 3.1.7
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'invest' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['invest/\\(\\?P(?P<pk>[^/]+)\\\\d\\+\\)/$']
Exception Location: C:\Users\Harsh-PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py, line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
Python Executable:  C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.9
Python Path:    
['E:\\Colosseum 2021\\django_colo',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37',
 'C:\\Users\\Harsh-PC\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Harsh-PC\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\Harsh-PC\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Harsh-PC\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 22 Mar 2021 09:21:50 +0000
```

- I am calling `invest` page from `brand.html` page in this manner

```
        <a href="{% url 'invest' pk=marking.id %}";><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" >Invest</button></a>
```

- I am passing the value properly in my `html` code

```
<script>
                $(document).on('submit', '#post-form',function(e){
                    // console.log("Amount="+$('input[name="amount"]').val());
                    e.preventDefault();
                    // getting the value entered
                    amount = $('input[name="amount"]').val();
                    product_title = $('input[name="product_title"]').val();
                    console.log("Product title="+product_title);
                    console.log("Amount entered by user="+amount);
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url:"{% url 'invest' pk=context.id %}",
                        data:{
                            product_title: product_title,
                            amount: amount,
                            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
                            action: 'post'
                        },
                        success: function(xhr, errmsg, err){
                          window.location = "brand"
                        },
                        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                        $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
                            " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>");
                        console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); 
                    }
                    });
                });
              </script>
```

- `urls.py`

```
path('invest/(?P<pk>\d+)/', views.invest, name='invest'),
```

- `views.py`

```
def invest(request, pk):
    # fetching the current event details
    event_data = MarketingMaestro.objects.get(pk = pk)
    context = {
            'id' : event_data.id,
            'product_title' : event_data.product_title,
            'total_value' : event_data.total_value,
            'total_votes' : event_data.total_votes,
            }

    # fetching user details
    user_data = MarketingInvesment.objects.get(emailID = request.user.email)
    user_details = {
        'name' : user_data.name,
        'emailID' : user_data.emailID,
        'remaining_amount' : user_data.remaining_amount
    }

    total_value_db = event_data.total_value 

    # updating the user amount
    # try:
        # checking if the user exist in UserProfile through the logged in email id
    if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
        response_data = {}
        name = request.user.username
        emailID = request.user.email
        # remaining amount from db
        remaining_amount = user_data.remaining_amount
        product_title = request.POST.get('product_title')
        # getting user amount
        user_amount = request.POST.get('amount')
        user_amount_final = int(user_amount)

        user_amount_db = total_value_db + user_amount_final
        final_amount = remaining_amount - user_amount_final

        response_data['name'] = name
        response_data['emailID'] = emailID
        response_data['remaining_amount'] = remaining_amount
        response_data['product_title'] = product_title
            # updating the current logged in user values
        user_data = MarketingInvesment.objects.get(emailID = request.user.email)
        if(user_data.emailID == request.user.email):
            MarketingInvesment.objects.filter(emailID = request.user.email).update(
                name = name,
                emailID = emailID,
                remaining_amount = final_amount,
                product_title = product_title,
                total_investment = user_amount_db
            )
        return render(request, 'invest.html')
    return render(request, 'invest.html', {'context' : context, 'user_details' : user_details})
```

Comment: **Just a thought**
 - Do I need to create one more method, as I am calling the same method again, is that causing the issue ?

Comment: can you share the full error trace back

Comment: @c.grey I have updated that now you can check

Comment: what is **context.id** ????? in your Ajax

Comment: Where do you get marking.id? This is a parameter that you specify in your url statement but this parameter is not submitted in the request view.

Comment: @c.grey ```context.id``` is an unique entry in the table through which I will updating some value into the table.

Comment: @S.A ```marking.id``` is used when i click on a particular event. I have multiple events listed and hen clicked on a particular one through ```marking.id``` i open that particular event in which i am doing the investment task.

Comment: I have answered the question you can check I think that's the problem of your regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

- `urls.py`

```
path('investing/<int:pk>/', views.investing, name='investing'),
path('invest/<int:pk>/', views.invest, name='invest'),
```

- `views.py` Just had to include JsonResponse as I was returning render which is wrong.

```
return JsonResponse(
            {
                'message': "success"
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use url when working with URL regex, because path doesn't support regex here is the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#path) for path(). you can use regex in url like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

url(r'^invest/(?P<pk>[\w-]+)/', views.invest, name='invest'),
...
```

and I think you didn't add marking object in your context

Comment: That doesn't solve my error. Still I am facing the error.

Comment: and another thing that I saw in your code, did you add marking object in your context?

Comment: Yes, that I am retrieving from the database and passing it to the ```invest.html```

Comment: how you retrieved it from the database without rendering it to the context dictionary?

Comment: You can check the invest method, i have retrieved and then rendered, in the last line I have passed it also ```return render(request, 'invest.html', {'context' : context, 'user_details' : user_details})```

Comment: can you also share your brand views()? because I think you need to add marking objects to the context of your brand views()

Comment: I have updated the brand view in my question.

Comment: or did you debug the ```brand.html``` page that did you receive the value of marking.id?

Comment: I am receiving the marking.id and everything is working fine in the fetching side. The issue is when I submit the value at that point I am facing the issue due to the ```pk``` value i am passing.

Comment: ```Reverse for 'invest' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}'``` this message shows that you are not getting value of marking.id

Comment: and one thing are you iterating it with loop? because you added ```marking_maestro``` key on your context and used marking in ```brand.html```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230220/discussion-between-lav-sharma-and-muhammad-hammad).

Comment: @LavSharma okay

Comment: I am waiting for you in a room

Comment: Check the room once